# Why cant i order all these items into a column using flex box

Tags: html, css, flask

So for some reason I can't get these inputs into a flex box and then order them vertically. Below are the html and css. Instead of ordering them in a column the flex box bunches them all up see link for photo provided by SO.

Screenshot of what is shown:

[image: Screenshot of what is shown]

Ideas welcome. Thanks in advance!

**CSS**

```
<style>
    body {
      background-image: url("static/Images/Screen Shot 2021-08-18 at 10.45.56 PM.png");
      background-size: 100vw;
    }

    .bottom-left {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 84%;
       left: 13%;
       font-size: 150%;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       font: Georgia;
       width: 12%;
    }

    .fname {
       position: absolute;
       font-size: 95%;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       border-radius: 3px;
       width: 12%;
    }

    .sub {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 95%;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;  
        border: 1.7px solid white;
        width: 8%; 
        height: 4%;
        width: 12%;
    }

    .lname {
       position: absolute;
       font-size: 95%;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       border-radius: 3px;
       font: Georgia;
       width: 12%;
    }

    .add1 {
       position: absolute;
       font-size: 95%;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       border-radius: 3px;
       font: Georgia;
       width: 12%;
    }

    .add2 {
       position: absolute;
       font-size: 95%;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       border-radius: 3px;
       font: Georgia;
       width: 12%;
    }

    .postal {
       position: absolute;
       font-size: 95%;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       border-radius: 3px;
       font: Georgia;
       width: 12%;
    }

    .country {
       position: absolute;
       font-size: 95%;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       border-radius: 3px;
       font: Georgia;
       width: 12%;
    }
 
   .city {
       position: absolute;
       font-size: 95%;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       border-radius: 3px;
       font: Georgia;
       width: 12%;
    }

    .state {
       position: absolute;
       font-size: 95%;
       color: white;
       background-color: black;
       border-radius: 3px;
       font: Georgia;
       width: 12%;
    }

    ::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
       color: white;
       font: Georgia;
       opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
    }

    .wrapper {
        display: flex;
    }

    .wrapper input[type="text"] {
       flex: 1 1 auto;
    }
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<title>task Page</title>
</head>
<body>
{%if msg%}
<p>{{msg}}</p>
{%endif%}
<label class="bottom-left" for="fname">First name</label>
<form name="tasks"action="/add-tasks" method="POST">
  <input class="fname" type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="FIRST NAME">
  <input class="lname" type="text" id="lname" name="fname" placeholder="LAST NAME">
  <input class="add1" type="text" id="add1" name="fname" placeholder="address 1">
  <input class="add2" type="text" id="add2" name="fname" placeholder="address 2">
  <input class="postal" type="text" id="postal" name="fname" placeholder="postal code">
  <input class="country" type="text" id="country" name="fname" placeholder="country">
  <input class="city" type="text" id="city" name="fname" placeholder="city">
  <input class="state" type="text" id="state" name="fname" placeholder="state">
  <input class="sub" type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute;` in all the inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use position absolute and expect flex to work. Put all of your inputs in a division and give display flex then say flex direction column

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I'll set a grid first with columns and rows and drop everything inside.